# Time Element dateTime Attribute and Content Formatting

Tags: html, date, markup, schema.org, microdata

What happens if Microdata reflects the text on the page but is not the same?

[`birthDate`](http://schema.org/birthDate) expects an ISO 8601 date. However I do not want to display the actual birth date, I want to display their age on my website. There is no age for [`Person`](http://schema.org/Person) and an age is not part of the ISO 8601 date format however the two do correlate. If I use a meta tag for date and display an age someplace on the page, would it be out of line? Would parsers understand that I am displaying the age and giving the date?

How am I suposed to display these dates?

http://schema.org/docs/gs.html#advanced_dates says that machines have a problem reading dates and to use

```
<time datetime="2011-04-01">04/01/11</time>
```

Does this mean anytime I display a date for any reason I should mark it up for this if I want bots to read it correctly? Does it matter if the date is a birthDate to a Person, the date the page was loaded, or something very random as the date the page was last viewed?

If I am supposed to use the `time` element, and that time is also a `birthDate` would I specify it as such:

```
<time itemprop='birthDate' datetime="2011-04-01">April 1, 2011</time>
```

Comment: This question is not on topic as defined in [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). If you don't understand why, please ask on [meta] for help.

Comment: It is not off topic at all as per the help center. It is a question about html5 formating of microdata which is an accepted question:a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development. albeit it is not Swift, Python, or node.js HTML5 questions are accepted

Comment: How to format microdata for a good SEO rank by google isn't on topic. You'd probably find more people who know how to format it properly over at [webmasters.se].

Comment: @will. As per Stack Overflow: "Only programming-related SEO questions are acceptable on StackOverflow." This is a programming related question as it asks how to format it it correctly, not what will improve my SEO rank with google. Mircro data does not help SEO in anyway so it is impossible for this to be an SEO related question. If you like, I could take off the SEO tag however, the question is on topic and belongs right here.

Comment: `Would Google understand that I am displaying the age and giving the date?` <- SEO question

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about SEO, not programming. SEO questions may be asked on [webmasters.se].

Comment: Asking how search engine bots would understand/interpret it (in "[…] understand that I am displaying the age and giving the date?"), is problematic, because we can’t know this (part of their secret algorithms etc.); this would be off-topic here. -- It would be on-topic to ask what HTML, Microdata, and Schema.org require/recommend/suggest. So if you edit out the part where we’d have to guess how search engines interpret it, I think this question can be re-opened.

Comment: Might as well close this question and condem it to the depths as it is soo old now. Maybe it could have been answered a long time ago but no one is looking at it now. Maybe someone will land on it from Google in 6 months from now which I really won't care then. Wait... can't say the world Google or the question will get put on hold.

Comment: I think it‘s a good question and should not be closed. How do you correctly markup something like „post created 5 days ago“ with microdata and how will it be interpreted by machines that understand and use microdata? I vote for opening the question again.

Comment: seo now includes everything under the sun, from google specific technologies, to not using popups/rwd (ui/ux/design/front-end), to page speed and wpo, which most certainly are for coders/programmers. all of these seo dismissals are holdovers from a different era. the answer is here: https://css-tricks.com/time-element/